# How to insert primary/foreign keys and there colums into an existing database?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

What is the best way to go about inserting primary/foreign key constraints and there columns of data into a large existing company database?

I currently am working at a company where the database is very large and there is very few primary keys and no foreign keys. I have noticed the issues this causes as someone who has always used these keys to join tables. There is lots of mismatched data which is causing a lot of issues when it comes to reporting with big queries. This almost creates more issues than there needs to be.

How would i go about improving an issue like this?

Any advice would be great. Thanks

Comment: Did you meant `how to import existing data into tables with out causing constraint violations ?`

Comment: Personally I wouldnt touch a large commercial database without help from a professional/experienced DB Analyst, not strangers on the internet. **Be very very careful**.

Comment: Yes, of course i would never do anything without other professional advice. It was more how i would go about proposing it to the company and its benefits etc

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about how to sell an idea than programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you definitely need to introduce Primary and Foreighn keys!!!

The syntax to add a primary key on an existing table is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n);
```

To delete a constraint is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name;
```

To disable:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DISABLE CONSTRAINT constraint_name;
```

if you need to do data cleansing the below will also come useful:

```
alter table t enable novalidate constraint uniq_a;
```

New records inserted will adhere to the contstrains but existing data will not be validated.

I can't think of anything else right now, but don't hesitate to ask me on comments.

Ted.